# visual studio designer dpi setting

Tags: visual-studio, forms, resize, dpi

I've learn how to manage different DPI settings the hard way, so that at runtime my applications are properly displayed.

But there is still a big issue with Design time Visual Studio.
Say I build an application at 96 dpi and I switch my display to 120 dpi for testing purposes.

Now IF I open a form designer at 120 dpi, the form is resized according to 125%, the controls moved aso! :-(((

So I try to avoid reopening forms, but that's NOT a nice solution, isn't it?

Is there by any chance a design time setting to prevent form to resize?

Comment: This is a duplicate of my question, also sadly unanswered. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074106/can-i-tell-visual-studio-not-to-change-the-dpi-of-a-project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a solution but possibly a workaround: do not test on your computer but on a VM or other computer and do not open the solution on a computer with big fonts.

And we found that we cannot use the AutoScaleMode = Dpi.Font setting. That will randomly resize forms when we open them in the designer. Dpi or None seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Although this question is already old, I want to share my workaround.

- Keep the Form’s `AutoScaleMode = Font`. This works fine, if you control the rest correctly.
- Set in your Forms Designer: `Font = MS Sans; 11px`. Basically, specify your Fonts in Pixel, instead of Points. So Visual Studio won't re-scale anything if the system's DPI change.
- In the Forms Ctor, after `InitializeComponent`, re-set: `Font = SystemFonts.DefaultFont`. Now, at run time, Fonts will use Point-based sizes again, and you get nice high-DPI GUI.
- Enable DPI-Awareness, either through a manifest or by API function SetProcessDPIAwareness

You can find the details of my (hard) learning trail on my Blog: http://www.sgrottel.de/?p=1581&lang=en