# My Windows Form is "shrunk" in Visual Studio Community Designer. Project originally created in VS Express 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vs-community-edition

I have a C# project which was originally created in VS Express v2010.  I recently upgraded to VS 2016 Community.  Now, when I open that project, the Windows form in that project appears "shrunk" in the Designer.  If I build & run, however, the form looks fine.

[image: Here's what it looks like in designer]

[image: ...And here's what it looks like at runtime]

I've tried playing with the DPI settings & screen resolution on my laptop; neither of these made a difference.

Obviously, trying to position objects on the form using the designer is virtually impossible since it is so compressed.  Any advise would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It looks to me like it is your running application that is actually displaying incorrectly.  The icons and font all have scaling artifacts.  Are you *sure* your DPI is set to 100%?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to set `AutoSize` and `AutoScale` properties to the following:

```
Form.AutoSize = false;
Form.AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.Font;
```

This could also be helpful: [AutoScaleMode problems with changed default font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973165/autoscalemode-problems-with-changed-default-font)

Comment: But how does that effect how the form looks in designer view?

Comment: You are right, it does not, but its seems DPI related thus its rather a workaround. Please check also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074106/can-i-tell-visual-studio-not-to-change-the-dpi-of-a-project